# Tile map Collision Detection

Tags: c#, dictionary, xna, collision-detection

I've been looking through the other questions but just can't seem to figure this out.. I'm using XNA in a custom tilemap loader. Here is the code.
http://pastebin.com/cuatQHTb

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;

namespace Pressure
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {


        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D player;
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.Zero;
        Vector2 playersp = new Vector2(50.0f, 50.0f);
        Texture2D road1;
        Texture2D road2;
        Texture2D brickwall;
        Texture2D floor1;
        Texture2D floor2;
        Texture2D floor3;
        Texture2D grass;
        Texture2D sidewalk1;
        Texture2D wood;
        Texture2D road3;
        private Vector2 origin;
        KeyboardState currentState;
        Camera camera = new Camera();

        Vector2 motion;

        List<Texture2D> tiles = new List<Texture2D>();

        static int tileWidth = 64;
        static int tileHeight = 64;

        int tileMapWidth;
        int tileMapHeight;

        static int screenWidth;
        static int screenHeight;

        static int mapWidthInPixels;
        static int mapHeightInPixels;
        int[,] map = {
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,},
              {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,},
              {9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9,},
              {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,},
              {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
                     };
        public static int ScreenWidth
        {
            get { return screenWidth; }
        }

        public static int ScreenHeight
        {
            get { return screenHeight; }
        }

        public static int MapWidthInPixels
        {
            get { return mapWidthInPixels; }
        }

        public static int MapHeightInPixels
        {
            get { return mapHeightInPixels; }
        }
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }


        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            player = Content.Load<Texture2D>("haz");
            origin.X = player.Width /2;
            origin.Y = player.Height /2;
            grass = Content.Load<Texture2D>("grass");
            floor1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("floor1");
            floor2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("floor2");
            floor3 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("floor3");
            wood = Content.Load<Texture2D>("wood");
            road1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("road1");
            road2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("road2");
            sidewalk1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("sidewalk1");
            brickwall = Content.Load<Texture2D>("brickwall");
            road3 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("road3");
            tiles.Add(grass); //0
            tiles.Add(floor1);//1
            tiles.Add(floor2);//2
            tiles.Add(floor3);//3
            tiles.Add(wood);//4
            tiles.Add(road1);//5
            tiles.Add(road2);//6
            tiles.Add(sidewalk1);//7
            tiles.Add(brickwall);//8
            tiles.Add(road3);//9

            tileMapWidth = map.GetLength(1);
            tileMapHeight = map.GetLength(0);

            mapWidthInPixels = tileMapWidth * tileWidth;
            mapHeightInPixels = tileMapHeight * tileHeight;

            screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
            screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
           }


        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
             }
        private float RotationAngle;
        private float oldx;
        private float oldy;

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            oldx = playersp.X;
            oldy = playersp.Y;
    currentState = Keyboard.GetState();
   pos = playersp;

            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            IsMouseVisible = true;


            MouseState Mouses = Mouse.GetState();
            Vector2 mouseLook = new Vector2(Mouses.X, Mouses.Y);

            motion = Vector2.Zero;
            Vector2 direction = (playersp ) - mouseLook; 
            float angle = (float)(Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X));

            RotationAngle = angle ; 
            if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                if (playersp.Y > screenHeight  /4)
                {
                    playersp.Y = playersp.Y - 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    ScrollUp();

                }
            }
            if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                if (playersp.X > screenWidth / 4)
                {

                        playersp.X = playersp.X - 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    ScrollLeft();


                }
            }
            if (currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) 
            {
                if (playersp.Y > screenHeight / 1.5f)
                {
                    ScrollDown();
                }else{
                    playersp.Y = playersp.Y + 1; 
                }

            }
            if (currentState.IsKeyDown( Keys.D))
            {

                if (playersp.X > screenWidth / 1.5f)
                {

                    ScrollRight();
                }
                else
                {
                    playersp.X = playersp.X + 1;

                }

            }
            if (motion != Vector2.Zero)
            {
                motion.Normalize();

                camera.Position += motion * camera.Speed;
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        private void ScrollUp()
        {
            motion.Y = -0.5f;
        }

        private void ScrollRight()
        {
            motion.X = 0.5f;
        }

        private void ScrollDown()
        {
            motion.Y = 0.5f;
        }

        private void ScrollLeft()
        {
            motion.X = -0.5f;
        }

        private Point VectorToCell(Vector2 vector)
        {
            return new Point(
                        (int)(vector.X / tileWidth),
                        (int)(vector.Y / tileHeight));
        }

        private Vector2 ViewPortVector()
        {
            return new Vector2(
                    screenWidth + tileWidth,
                    screenHeight + tileHeight);
        }


        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            DrawMap();




            base.Draw(gameTime);

        }

        private void DrawMap()
        {
            Point cameraPoint = VectorToCell(camera.Position);
            Point viewPoint = VectorToCell(camera.Position +
                                ViewPortVector());

            Point min = new Point();
            Point max = new Point();

            min.X = cameraPoint.X;
            min.Y = cameraPoint.Y;
            max.X = (int)Math.Min(viewPoint.X, map.GetLength(1));
            max.Y = (int)Math.Min(viewPoint.Y, map.GetLength(0));

            Rectangle tileRectangle = new Rectangle(
                    0,
                    0,
                    tileWidth,
                    tileHeight);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            for (int y = min.Y; y < max.Y; y++)
            {
                for (int x = min.X; x < max.X; x++)
                {
                    tileRectangle.X = x * tileWidth - (int)camera.Position.X;
                    tileRectangle.Y = y * tileHeight - (int)camera.Position.Y;

                    spriteBatch.Draw(tiles[map[y, x]],
                        tileRectangle,
                        Color.White);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(player, pos, null, Color.White, RotationAngle,
      origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
                }
            }

            spriteBatch.End();
        }

    }
}
```

How would I detect the tiles position and make sure the player doesn't enter that tile? thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question: you have a map of 0-9; tiles associated with each value; I assume you know the player's position in the map; you can check whether where they want to move is a tile type they should not.  In that case don't change the position of the player -- did I misunderstood something?  Or is this the solution you were asking about?

Comment: @user1042757, please paste code that you need advice with into the question instead of providing a link. If code is longer than 10 lines it is likely that your question is about something else... so review your code and question together to make sure if both makes sense together related.

Comment: @Attila 

I want to find if the player is about to move into the wrong tile, then make sure it cannot move. Lets say like in the movement
when the player presses a button to move the sprite I want to check and see what tile it is moving into, and if it is moving into a "wall" tile I want to make sure it cannot.

Comment: @user1042757 Did you get it right? If yes please help me out, im having the same problem that you were expereincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
private static float scalingFactor = 10;
private static float mapSizeX = 19;
private static float mapSizeY = 29;
```

in `Update`:

```
if (playersp.Y > screenHeight  /4) {
  int mapX = (int) (playersp.X / scalingFactor);
  int mapY = (int) (playersp.Y / scalingFactor) - 1;
  if (isMovable(mapX, mapY)) {
    playersp.Y = playersp.Y - scalingFactor;
  }
} else {
  ScrollUp();
}
```

and a new method:

```
public bool isMovable(int mapX, int mapY)
{
  if (mapX < 0 || mapX > 19 || mapY < 0 || mapY > 29) {
    return false;
  }

  int tile = map[mapX, mapY];
  if (tile == 4 || tile == 8) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Similarly for the other directions.

The above code calls the function `isMovable` to decide whether the player can move to the new location based on the type of tile stored in the map at that position.  The decision is false (the player cannot move there) if it is wood or brick wall, otherwise it is true.

The scaling factor is to map between the screen position (captured in `playersp`) and the tile map.  In this case each tile is equivalent to 10 screen "pixels" (You can break it into two separate scales if you want to: one for X dimention, the other for Y).

Note, you need to make sure the values `mapSizeX` and `mapSizeY` are correct.

It would be best if you introduced named constants for the type of tile instead of using the numbers -- it will make your code more readable (for you in the future and for others reading it).

EDIT: updated code & explanation

Comment: Thank you so much! That sums everything up for me! I'll be sure to try it and I'll report back within the hour.

Comment: "Index was outside the bounds of the array." 
It gives me that right here: 
if (isMovable(map[newX, newY]))

Comment: What is the value of newX and newY?  The map is 19*29 (if I counted correctly), so the indices should not be larger than that.  I believe you initialize the player's position to 50, 50, which is outside the boundaries (even if they move once).  If the 50,50 is correct, you need to scale it down for the map indices, otherwise choose a valid starting coordinate.  In either case, you need to ensure the user does not leave the map or you will get the same error.

Comment: Hmm...Sounds good but I don't think I'm drawing the character to the map. What it is doing is drawing the player to the screen giving the illusion of it being on the map. How would I just draw the character to the map?

Comment: See updated answer.  You can do the drawing as you did before.  When it comes to consider whether the user can move to a particular tile, you scale the screen position coordinates down to map into the tile map indices.

Comment: Now need needs an object reference for " int tile = map[mapX, mapY];"

Comment: What do you mean by "needs an object reference"?  If you are referring to a compiler error, please copy it verbatim.

Comment: "Error 3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Pressure.Game1.map' C:\Users\asd\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Pressure\Pressure\Pressure\Game1.cs 341 17 Pressure
"

What it looks like it needs the reference for is 'map'

Comment: My bad: remove static from `isMovable()` definition.

Comment: I am now back to the same problem... with the Index being outside the bounds of the array >.<

It only happens when the player leaves the upper left hand corner of the screen though..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9442/discussion-between-attila-and-user1042757)